# Gestionar grupos LINUX AMAZON AMI

Tags: ec2

Tengo un problema con los grupos y sus usuarios, todo a partir de la creación de un blog para el sitio.

Resulta que para que el blog pueda cargar los archvios multimedia, tuve que dar acceso ala carpeta del blog al usuario "apache".

Entonces, para cargar, descargar, y gestionar algunas partes del blog tuve que instalar vsftpd, como consecuencia cree un usuario ftp.

Y bueno, para editar archivos (sobre todo algunas líneas de código pequeño), acceso desde SFTP utilizando WinSCP.

Entonces para que el blog funcionara, tuve que hacer esto:

```
sudo chown -R apache /var/www/
```

Ahí se murió todo, por ftp puedo listar los directorios pero no puedo bajar ni subir, por SFTP me pasa lo mismo entonces...

¿Como puedo crear un grupo de usuarios, por ejemplo que se llame www y despues, a ese grupo de usuarios darle permisos a mi directorio /var/www?

Gracias >.<